# jQuery UI Autocomplete with multiple selection is not showing data in html page

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to work with an autocomplete text box with multiple selection. But, I'm experiencing some troubles with an autocomplete component from jQueryUi. The list with autocomplete suggestions doesn't appear properly.
From server I've got the value like this:

```
[{"id":"1","text":"Test1 [1001]"},{"id":"2","text":"Test2 [1002]"}]
```

But it's not showing at UI. At UI it's like this:

[image: The Group field]

Here is my HTML code:

```
<label class="control-label">Group <span class="symbol required" aria-required="true"></span></label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="HSModels" tablename="ProductInfo" required />
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="HSModelsID" required />
```

My Script:

```
 $("#HSModels")
            .bind("keydown", function (event) {
                if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                $(this).data("ui-autocomplete").menu.active) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            })
            .autocomplete({
                minLength: 2,
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.getJSON("/api/Common/AutoCompleteListDataByTableName", { tableName: "ProductInfo", query: request.term },
                        response
                        );
                },
                search: function () {
                    // custom minLength
                    var term = extractLast(this.value);
                    if (term.length < 2) {
                        return false;
                    }
                },
                focus: function () {
                    // prevent value inserted on focus
                    return false;
                },
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    var HSModelsIDVal = $("#HSModelsID").val();
                    HSModelsIDVal += ", " + ui.item.id;
                    $("#HSModelsID").val(HSModelsIDVal)

                    var terms = split(this.value);
                    // remove the current input
                    terms.pop();
                    // add the selected item
                    terms.push(ui.item.value);
                    // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                    terms.push("");
                    this.value = terms.join(", ");
                    return false;
                }
            //});
        });
        function split(val) {
            return val.split(/,\s*/);
        }
        function extractLast(term) {
            return split(term).pop();
        }
```

And at server side:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage AutoCompleteListDataByTableName(string tableName, string query = "")
        {
            GenericRepository<DropdownListData> repository = new GenericRepository<DropdownListData>(_csmDb);

            try
            {
                var parameters = new List<SqlParameter> { new SqlParameter("@TableName", tableName), new SqlParameter("@QueryText", query) };
                List<DropdownListData> dataList = repository.ExecuteStoreProcedureToList("[GetAutoCompleteListDataByTableName]", parameters);
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, dataList, RequestFormat.JsonFormaterString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new Confirmation { output = "error", msg = ex.Message }, RequestFormat.JsonFormaterString());
            }          

        }
```

Any thoughts? And I've face another problem, i.e., after selecting one it's not loading the data again.

**At firebug:**

1st time: GET http://localhost:40315/api/Common/AutoCompleteListDataByTableName?tableName=ProductInfo&query=te

And 2nd time:
GET http://localhost:40315/api/Common/AutoCompleteListDataByTableName?tableName=ProductInfo&query=%2C+te

I'm following trying to do something [like this](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish what you want, you have to follow the example you mentioned and the example for '[Custom Data & Display](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data)'. Here is what I would suggest:

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/gr5LL10o/

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  $("#HSModels")
    .bind("keydown", function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
        $(this).data("ui-autocomplete").menu.active) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    })
    .autocomplete({
      minLength: 2,
      source: function(request, response) {
        /*
          $.getJSON("/api/Common/AutoCompleteListDataByTableName", {
              tableName: "ProductInfo",
              query: request.term
            },
            response
          );
          */
          // Example search for demonstration, using jsfiddle AJAX system
        $.ajax({
          url: "/echo/json/",
          type: "POST",
          data: {
            json: JSON.stringify([{
              "id": "1",
              "text": "Test1 [1001]"
            }, {
              "id": "2",
              "text": "Test2 [1002]"
            }, {
              "id": "3",
              "text": "Apple [1003]"
            }, {
              "id": "4",
              "text": "Banana [1004]"
            }])
          },
          success: function(data) {
            var results = [];
            var term = extractLast(request.term).toLowerCase();
            $.each(data, function(k, v) {
              if (v.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) === 0) {
                console.log("Found " + v.text);
                results.push(v);
              }
            });
            console.log("Responding with ", results);
            response(results);
          }
        });
      },
      focus: function() {
        // prevent value inserted on focus
        return false;
      },
      select: function(event, ui) {
      /*
        var HSModelsIDVal = $("#HSModelsID").val();
        HSModelsIDVal += ", " + ui.item.id;
        $("#HSModelsID").val(HSModelsIDVal)
      */
        var labels = split(this.value);
        var ids = split($("#HSModelsID").val());
        // remove the current input
        labels.pop();
        ids.pop();
        // add the selected item
        labels.push(ui.item.text);
        ids.push(ui.item.id);
        // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
        labels.push("");
        ids.push("");
        this.value = labels.join(", ");
        $("#HSModelsID").val(ids.join(","));
        return false;
      }
    }).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
      return $("<li>")
        .append("<div>" + item.text + "</div>")
        .appendTo(ul);
    };

  function split(val) {
    return val.split(/,\s*/);
  }

  function extractLast(term) {
    return split(term).pop();
  }
});
```

There was nothing outwardly wrong with your original code. Your data was more complex than the standard array of data. You were also doing more with it than just making a list.

For the purpose of the example, I bypassed your AJAX call to your API. I am assuming that the data being returned from a lookup will be like the following:

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "text": "Test1 [1001]"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "text": "Test2 [1002]"
}, {
    "id": "3",
    "text": "Apple [1003]"
}, {
    "id": "4",
    "text": "Banana [1004]"
}]
```

This is my example data, your data will already be filtered. So in your script the success function would be much simpler, more like:

```
success: function(data){
  response(data),
},
```

In the selection phase, we're going to do a bit more with the results. We want to create an array of labels and IDs. Thus when the user selects a specific label, we update that array, and update the corresponding array of IDs that we can use later.

I do just this, I create an array of all the labels currently selected and an array of all the IDs currently selected. We drop the last entry in that array, for labels this will be the portion of the search term, and for the IDs this will be empty. We push the most recent selection on to the end of the array and write them into their respective fields.

The last bit we have to do to tidy things up is renter the result list items. Since we do not need the ID, we basically omit that and make a li of just the Text labels.

Ta da! Comment and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: one more query, how to remove the id from the hidden field if one item deleted from the text-box after selecting?

Comment: @Metaphor that would take a fair amount of work. Consider wrapping label with something and adding a `x` button. This way, you can get the label's index and pop that item from both arrays.

Comment: @Twisty Perfect